# Diameter of component graph of uniform spanning forests on the amenable transitive graph with super polynomial growth

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

According to the paper [Benjamini, Kesten, Peres, and Schramm - Geometry of the uniform spanning forest: transitions in dimensions 4, 8, 12](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0107140) (Annals, 2004), the diameter of the component graph of the uniform spanning forests (USF) on $d$-dimensional transitive graph is $\lfloor(d-1)/4\rfloor$.

I wonder if the diameter of the component graph of the USF on the amenable transitive graph with superpolynomal growth is infinite. Actually, I think the answer is yes for every transitive graph with superpolynomial growth. A concrete example is that I think the component graph of WUSF on 3-regular tree has infinite diameter. But 3-regular tree is not amenable.

Comment: You said that the diametre was $[n - 1]/4$, but it seemed that you meant $\lfloor(d - 1)/4\rfloor$.  I edited accordingly; I hope that was correct.

Comment: Why do you think the component graph of the USF on 3-regular tree has infinite diameter? I think that the component graph of the USF consists of a single point, i.e. the tree itself.

Comment: @LeechLattice no! Actually, the Free USF of 3-regular tree has just  one component, but the Wired USF of 3-regular tree and has infinite diameter.

Comment: @noneYuan Do you mean "WUSF" in the sentence "I wonder if the diameter of the component graph of the USF on the amenable transitive graph with superpolynomal growth is infinite"?

Comment: @LeechLattice WUSF and FUSF coincide on d-dimensional transitive graph, so we just use USF.